# Given a 3 dimensional cube, find n points such that their pairwise distances are maximum

Tags: geometry

I want to find the embedding of n points in a cube such that they are all maximally separated from each other. I think that all pairwise distances cannot be the same for points greater than 4(which happens for a tetrahedron). I want to find out some approximation points such that all points are as far away from each other as possible(average separation).

Comment: Do you want to maximize the minimum separation or the average separation or some other statistic? Can you solve the problem for the square? I think the problem is hard - if you tell us why you need the answer that may help. Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: It might be helpful to start out with a square. I agree with Ethan, this seems like a very difficult problem. This paper could be useful: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-mathematical-bulletin/article/densest-packing-of-9-circles-in-a-square/3012C0C296366EE9C0E95CD534DB5EF3

Comment: @EthanBolker I am talking about average separation

Comment: I assume you want to maximize $\frac{2}{n(n-1)}\sum\limits_{1\le i < j\le n}|p_i - p_j|$ where $p_i \in [0,1]^3$ is the position of $i^{th}$ point. I believe you need to place them on vertices of the cube. It come down to $|p|$ is a convex function in $p$ (in fact, strictly convex along any non-radial direction). In the optimal configuration, unless all the points lie on a line (which seems unlikely), they need to be [extreme points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) of the cube (ie. the 8 vertices).

Comment: @achillehui But i need to put n points inside the cube. Specifically, i was looking for n=19.

Comment: If by "inside", you mean in the interior of a cube, then it is impossible. The strict convexity I mention before implies if $p_1,\ldots, p_n \in [0,1]^3$ with $p_1 \in (0,1)^3$, then by choosing any unit vector $t$ not parallel to at least one of $p_j - p_1, 2 \le j \le n$ and small enough $\epsilon$ to make both $p_1 \pm \epsilon t \in [0,1]^3$, then at least one of the configuration $(p_1 \pm \epsilon t, p_2, \ldots, p_n)$ have larger average distance.

Comment: @achillehui I am not sure if I understood your argument completely but it can't be impossible. With your construction of new points, you are implying that you can construct points with a larger average distance. But you can't keep on doing this ad infinitum as the maximum average distance of the points is bounded by above(it can't be larger than the length of the diagonal of the cube).

Comment: I means in any optimal configuration, none of the points $p_i$ belongs to $(0,1)^3$. Same argument applies to points on interior of the face and a modification makes the argument works for points on interior of the edges. The end result is in any optimal configuration, all points $p_i$ belongs to the $8$ vertices $\{0,1\}^3$.